# Rounding numbers to n decimals in clojure

Tags: clojure

When I do, for example, (/ 1.0 7.0), I only get 17 digits: 0.14285714285714285. How can I get more then that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `BigDecimal` numbers and `with-precision`:

```
(with-precision 50 (/ 1M 7))
=> 0.14285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714M
```

Comment: Yeah, that was pretty much straightforward. Lame of me to ask such questions. Big thanks!

Comment: Observe, even with-precision and BigDecimal is rounding off at some point and that the digits 142857 are just repeated infinitely. (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction)

Comment: Clojure docs: [`with-precision`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/with-precision)

Comment: Do note though that with-precision parameter doesn't specify decimal places but total digits of precision; `(with-precision 3 (/ 11.111M 1)) => 11.1M` and `(with-precision 3 (/ 1.111M 1)) => 1.11M` - this is a small but sometimes important difference.

Answer (score 10):

Clojure (and pretty much all lisps) has ratio type that way you do not lose precision. do all your calculations with ratio and convert to double/float at the last minute to avoid precision problems.

Comment: However, be careful with ratios.  For example, if you keep multiplying ratios repeatedly, you may end up with huge numerators and denominators.  This can get very slow and can use a lot of RAM.